# How do I delete a folder and its files and subfolders and subfolders' files recursively?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I delete the folder `{app}\manuals` in Inno Setup during installation including all of its files and subfolders recursively?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the following to work:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\manuals"
```

The `[InstallDelete]` section is executed as the first step during installation.